# Is there a drag amount or drag scale for draggables in jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to move my draggable a certain ratio according to how far the mouse has moved.

For example, if the scale is 1:2 and the mouse is moved 10px to the right then the draggable would move 20px.

I have my draggable set up to scroll horizontally within a DIV and snapping to a grid.

Is this maybe in the docs and somehow I missed it? How can I achieve this?

Comment: play me a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am not going to start re-inventing the wheel if code exists for this already. The concept makes sense, yes? I'm just not ready to start dipping into the draggable event code and calculating positions just yet - if I have to do that, I will end up answering my own question.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? I'm asking you to put some demo code on jsFiddle. It might give more insight than your vague question does.

Comment: It's not vague. Just use your imagination or have a look at the jquery-ui droppable demo's http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no off-the-shelf option for this.  You'd need to bind to the drag event and do something smart with it, like update the elements position based on the mouse's original position and current position.

However, it's not all that difficult to do.  Here's a simple sample and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/29QKb/):

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        ui.position.top = (ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top) / 2;
        ui.position.left = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left) / 2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the confirmation. As much as I dislike answering my own question, I definitely will post the code I come up with to handle this.

Comment: added a simple code sample and jsfiddle that does what you're looking for.  It's fairly straight forward, you just figure out how much it thinks you've moved, and cut it in half.

Comment: Cool, this should do nicely. You had it backwards though. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/29QKb/10/ I just changed /2 to *2

Comment: Actually, it looks like it wants to go back to the starting position after you drop it and then drag again. This gives me plenty to go on though.

Comment: I suspect that on the start event, you might need to override the originalPosition in the underlying widget code, look in `$(this).data("draggable")`

Comment: I just thought, you could probably store the draggable position during the stop event and use that instead of ui.originialPosition . Maybe store it using .data() ? I'll have to check this out later.